# Reverse for 'patient_update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['patients/update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I made a view where users can edit the patients information and as I'm using a custom user model I had to make a custom update/delete view.The views are working when i enter them manually by the url but when i put a link reference to them by an anchor tag i get an error that it can't access the pk,I tried following many answers here and vids on YT but the error is still there

Views.py

```
def PatientUpdateView(request,pk=None):

    patient = get_object_or_404(models.Patient, pk=pk)
    form = forms.PatientForm(request.POST or None ,instance=patient)
    if form.is_valid() :
        patient = form.save(commit=False)
        patient.save()
        messages.success(request,"patient updated!")
        context = {
            'patient': patient,
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request,'patients/patient_edit_form_success.html',context)
    else:
        context = {
            'patient' : patient,
            'form': form,
                   }
        return render(request, 'patients/patient_edit_form.html', context)
```

and here's how i call it in an anchor tag

```
 <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{% url 'patients:patient_update' patient.pk %}">Open</a>
```

I tried

```
pk = patient.pk
pk = pk
```

and many other ways of calling it.

urls.py 
 here's the url pattern that i use

```
    path('update/<int:pk>', views.PatientUpdateView, name='patient_update'),
```

Comment: Please share your `urls.py`.

Comment: Are you sure by the way that the error is *not* located in `patient_edit_form_success.html` (or the other one)?

Comment: just edited it in the post

Comment: no it's located in the view where i'm trying to put the button.

Comment: Does the error happen on first load of the page or after a successful POST?

Comment: no the page doesn't even load.

Comment: Have you tried pk=patient.pk in the url tag?

Comment: yup i typed that in the post.

Comment: Do you know which path is being taken? Can you share the form and model for Patient?

Comment: The url is working manually as i could edit/delete patients just by typing the url/pk of the patients so i don't think this is a problem of the model/form

Comment: Do you know which template is being rendered?

Comment: do you mean in the button tag ? yes it's the update template.

Comment: No, in your view. Are both templates calling the same url tag in the same way? Have you debugged to see what patient is and what pk it has before it is rendered?

Comment: Now i'm focused on the update/edit view and when it works the delete should follow the same way, yes i tried seeing each patient pk and accessing them by their id in the detail view.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `<a>` tag to the following:

`<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{% url 'patient_update' patient.pk %}">Open</a>`

No name-spacing is needed when giving the url name.  Also, remember to `{% load static %}` in your template file.